# Unicode characters become question marks after inserting into the database

Tags: php, mysql, unicode, utf-8

When I insert some text written in Unicode into database, they become question marks. Database encoding is set to UTF-8. What else may be incorrect? When I check in phpMyAdmin there are question marks inserted only!

This is the code I use for connecting to database:

```
define ("DB_HOST", "localhost"); // Set database host
define ("DB_USER", "root"); // Set database user
define ("DB_PASS","password"); // Set database password
define ("DB_NAME","name"); // Set database name

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die("Couldn't make connection.");
$db = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link) or die("Couldn't select database");

mysql_set_charset('utf8',$link);
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
```

Comment: Which module do you use to communicate with MySQL? mysql, mysqli, pdo-mysql, ... ? The data is also properly utf-8 encoded? Exactly where do you see the characters as question marks?

Comment: I added mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); after mysql_select_db and the problem is solved!

Comment: You might wish to check out http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php

Answer (score 4):

Is the text you inserted encoded in UTF-8 too? Or is your PHP files not UTF-8? Have you set the MySQL Client connection to UTF-8?

If not, then that is probably the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

How do you know the become question marks? Do you see them as question marks on your PHP pages, when you output the database fields, or in software like [phpMyAdmin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpMyAdmin)?

Either way, the problem is probably the encoding of your web page rather than the database's. Make sure to add the following line:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: the font you're using is important information that could help in the resolution of this case

Answer (score 1):

```
 // First make sure your file produce UTF-8 characters
 header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
 // Make sure with your spelling
 // write
 mysql_query("SET CHARSET utf8");
 // Instead of
 mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

 // For some reasons
 mysql_query("SET CHARSET SET utf8");
 // It works on some servers and for other servers not. I am not sure why.

 // Try using mysql_set_charset("utf8"); only without mysql_query("SET CHARSET utf8");
 // For me I had the same issue with my server
 // When I used mysql_set_charset("utf8"); only --> the problem solved
 // again make sure with your spelling and try again
```

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, but you are all wrong...

My friend King Julien, you just have to execute:

```
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
mysql_query("SET CHARSET utf8");
mysql_query("SET COLLATION_CONNECTION = 'utf8_unicode_ci'"); // This statement does the job!!! ;)
```

Have a nice day!